# For Android, can I place the settings button in Tab bar instead of Tool Bar?

Tags: android, toolbar, tabbar

According to Android's material guidelines for Settings, settings "should not be frequently accessed (move these to toolbar)." Settings should be in toolbar menu like:

[image]

However, I see MANY apps that put settings part of the tab bar. Periscope is a good example, the settings is part of their tab bar:

[image]

Toolbar takes up too much room, I won't have any other button but Settings on Toolbar, so would Google allow me to put the app in play store with settings in Tab bar like Periscope instead of Tool bar? I think it's more convenient and takes up less space.

Comment: Yes, why not. 
Those are just guidelines, not strict rules one has to follow. 
You might find this interesting:
http://www.androidauthority.com/google-ignoring-its-own-material-design-guidelines-703149/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have misinterpreted the section you have quoted.

> settings "should not be frequently accessed (move these to toolbar)."

Here's how that bit appears in the official guidelines:

[image]

This portion of the document is saying that the concept of "Settings" shouldn't be applied to actions that a user might take frequently/repeatedly during the normal course of interaction with your app.

To create an example, imagine that your app is displaying a user's music library. You want to allow the user the ability to switch between "song view" and "album view". The choice of whether to view their library in song mode or album mode shouldn't be hidden inside your Settings screen, it should be available in the `Toolbar` on whichever screen displays the user's library.

You also asked:

> would Google allow me to put the app in play store with settings in Tab bar like Periscope instead of Tool bar?

Yes. The Material Design Guidelines are simply suggestions on how to design your app. You are free to use a different design style and make different choices in how to implement your user interface.